# Compare json objects with csv file

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, string-comparison

### Edit: So far my code is finding the comparisons. Am working on appending the JSON object data to the row of where the word matching occurs.

I'm trying to find the matching words between my JSON file and my CSV  then check where that word has a low rating(the column with decimal values) from the CSV.

If the word has low rating. I record the time of the word and the index of the word (edited). **Is there a way for me to use something like pandas to loop over all my json objects and append the objects' data when words are matching on the rightmost column of my csv?**

### Edit(Per the answers given below):

```
row,col = dfSynsets.shape
for value in contents['words']:
    current_word = value['word']
    for csv_row in range(row):
        curr_csv_word = dfSynsets.loc[csv_row][-1]
        if curr_csv_word == current_word:
            print(curr_csv_word)
            print(current_word)
```

This code block produces this output:

```
universe
universe
in
in
apparent
apparent
mention
mention
passing
passing
way
way
even
even
over
over
there
there
total
total
experiment
experiment
most
most
work
work
by
by
low
low
empty
empty
in
in
fill
fill
```

Here's an example of my json file

## Json File:

```
{
        "transcript": "The universe is bustling with matter and energy. Even in the vast apparent emptiness of intergalactic space, there's one hydrogen atom per cubic meter. That's not the mention a barrage of particles and electromagnetic radiation passing every which way from stars, galaxies, and into black holes. There's even radiation left over from the Big Bang. So is there such thing as a total absence of everything? This isn't just a thought experiment. Empty spaces, or vacuums, are incredibly useful. Inside our homes,  most vacuum cleaners work by using a fan to create a low-pressure relatively empty area that sucks matter in to fill the void. But that's far from empty. There's still plenty of matter bouncing around. Manufacturers rely on more thorough, sealed vacuums for all sorts of purposes. That includes vacuum-packed food that stays fresh longer, and the vacuums inside early light bulbs that protected filaments from degrading. These vacuums are generally created with some version of what a vacuum cleaner does using high-powered pumps that create enough suction to remove as many stray atoms as possible. But the best of these industrial processes tends to leave hundreds of millions of atoms per cubic centimeter of space. That isn't empty enough for scientists who work on experiments, like the Large Hadron Collider, where particle beams need to circulate at close to the speed of light for up to ten hours without hitting any stray atoms. So how do they create a vacuum? The LHC's pipes are made of materials, like stainless steel, that don't release any  of their own molecules and are lined with a special coating to absorb stray gases. Raising the temperature  to 200 degrees Celsius burns off any moisture, and hundreds of vacuum pumps take two weeks to trap enough gas and debris out of the pipes for the collider's incredibly sensitive experiments. Even with all this, the Large Hadron Collider isn't a perfect vacuum. In the emptiest places, there are still about 100,000 particles per cubic centimeter. But let's say an experiment like that could somehow get every last atom out. There's still an unfathomably huge amount of radiation all around us that can pass right through the walls. Every second, about 50 muons from cosmic rays, 10 million neutrinos coming directly from the Big Bang, 30 million photons from the cosmic microwave background, and 300 trillion neutrinos from the Sun pass through your body. It is possible to shield vacuum chambers with substances, including water, that absorb and reflect this radiation, except for neutrinos. Let's say you've somehow removed all of the atoms and blocked all of the radiation. Is the space now totally empty? Actually, no. All space is filled with what  physicists call quantum fields. What we think of as subatomic particles, electrons and photons and their relatives, are actually vibrations in a quantum fabric that extends throughout the universe. And because of a physical law called the Heisenberg Principle, these fields never stop oscillating, even without any particles to set off the ripples. They always have some minimum fluctuation called a vacuum fluctuation. This means they have energy, a huge amount of it. Because Einstein's equations tell us that mass and energy are equivalent, the quantum fluctuations in every cubic meter of space have an energy that corresponds to a mass of about four protons. In other words, the seemingly empty space inside your vacuum would actually weigh a small amount. Quantum fluctuations have existed since the earliest moments of the universe. In the moments after the Big Bang, as the universe expanded, they were amplified and stretched out to cosmic scales. Cosmologists believe that these original quantum fluctuations were the seeds of everything we see today: galaxies and the entire large scale structure of the universe, as well as planets and solar systems. They're also the center of one of the greatest scientific mysteries of our time because according to the current theories, the quantum fluctuations in the vacuum of space ought to have 120 orders of magnitude more energy than we observe. Solving the mystery of that missing energy may entirely rewrite our understanding of physics and the universe. ",
        "words": [
            {
                "alignedWord": "the",
                "end": 6.31,
                "start": 6.17,
                "word": "The"
            },
            {
                "alignedWord": "universe",
                "end": 6.83,
                "start": 6.31,
                "word": "universe"
            },
            {
                "alignedWord": "is",
                "end": 7.05,
                "start": 6.85,
                "word": "is"
            },
            {
                "alignedWord": "bustling",
                "end": 7.4799999999999995,
                "start": 7.05,
                "word": "bustling"
            },
            {
                "alignedWord": "with",
                "end": 7.65,
                "start": 7.48,
                "word": "with"
            },
            {
                "alignedWord": "matter",
                "end": 7.970000000000001,
                "start": 7.65,
                "word": "matter"
            },
            {
                "alignedWord": "and",
                "end": 8.09,
                "start": 7.97,
                "word": "and"
            },
            {
                "alignedWord": "energy",
                "end": 8.579999,
                "start": 8.099999,
                "word": "energy"
            },
            {
                "alignedWord": "even",
                "end": 9.35,
                "start": 9.08,
                "word": "Even"
            },
            {
                "alignedWord": "in",
                "end": 9.439999,
                "start": 9.349999,
                "word": "in"
            },
            {
                "alignedWord": "the",
                "end": 9.53,
                "start": 9.44,
                "word": "the"
            },
            {
                "alignedWord": "vast",
                "end": 9.84,
                "start": 9.53,
                "word": "vast"
            },
            {
                "alignedWord": "apparent",
                "end": 10.17,
                "start": 9.84,
                "word": "apparent"
            },
            {
                "alignedWord": "emptiness",
                "end": 10.67,
                "start": 10.19,
                "word": "emptiness"
            },
            {
                "alignedWord": "of",
                "end": 10.8,
                "start": 10.67,
                "word": "of"
            }
        ]
}
```

Here's my csv file

## CSV File:

```
     572714       0.0 ['knocked out', 'kayoed', '"KOd"', 'out', 'stunned']                  "KOd"
0      1771194  0.500000                   ['get', '"get under ones skin"']    "get under ones skin"
1       462301  0.125000              ['south-southwest', '"sou-sou-west"']           "sou-sou-west"
2       250898  0.500000                             ['between', '"tween"']                  "tween"
3      2203763  0.400000                             ['thirteenth', '13th']                     13th
4      2202047  0.333333                                   ['first', '1st']                      1st
...        ...       ...                                                ...                      ...
5552   1848465  0.000000  ['move over', 'give way', 'give', 'ease up', '...                    yield
5553   7176243  0.000000            ['concession', 'conceding', 'yielding']                 yielding
5554  14425853  0.000000                                          ['youth']                    youth
5555   8541841  0.250000                      ['zone', 'geographical zone']                     zone
5556   1943718  0.500000  ['soar', 'soar up', 'soar upwards', 'surge', '...                     zoom
```

## Example of desired output

```
col1:synset  col2:rating col3:list col4:word col5:json data
9466280 0.5 ['universe', 'existence', 'creation', 'world', 'cosmos', 'macrocosm']   macrocosm  
{
                "alignedWord": "universe",
                "end": 178.109999,
                "start": 177.599999,
                "word": "universe"
            },
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your goal ? Can you clarify it please ?

Comment: I added some attempted code to clarify what I'm trying to do in my question @OmarAldakar

Comment: Provide some examples so that others can debug and help you in this question.

Comment: I provided some attempted code @nikhilesh_koshti

Comment: Please provide a valid .json to copy paste, also provide a sample of what you want your data to look like.

Are you using .json or .csv?

Comment: Yes this json do not seem to be valid

Comment: I've added more of what my json actually is. But not the entire thing due to how large the json file is. So I hope this snippet is sufficient. @OmarAldakar

Comment: ^ @Ukrainian-serge

Comment: You must make sure you can load the snippet you provided to us. Once you do that, post the code you used to load that snippet here.   
Next: post the printed df here. 
NEXT: provide a sample of what you want the output table to look like.

Comment: You are supposed to provide a [mcve]. That means *something* that allow us to reproduce the problem. You did not. My best advice here is to add `print(i)` just above the offending line. You would add least know (and could tell us) what is `i`...

Comment: Implemented a reproducible example above that prints the matches. I wish to build off this to append json object data to the rows where the matches occur. Hope my edits have helped a bit, my knowledge of producing good questions on stack overflow is small due to just having started @SergeBallesta

Answer (score 0):

First define a mapping function :

```
import json
import pandas

def apply_fun (row):
    for value in contents['words']
        if value['word'] in row['word'] :
            return json.dumps(value)
    return ""
```

Then add it to your dataframe  :

```
x = dfSynsets.apply(lambda row : apply_fun(row),axis=1)
dfSynsets.insert(4,'json_ref',x)
```

Comment: Thanks! It prints the equal and non-equal checkers. But when I switch the logic to retrieve the respective words I get: "a
charitable
a
charity
a
charm
a
charter
a
chartered
a
chartless
a." Which I assume is printing based off an instance of the letter a in the word rather than the word A. Is there a way to fix my conditionals to compensate for such?

Comment: @AlanTram Can you check my edit, is it what you want ? If it is consider upvoting or validating the answer

Comment: Running this code block outputs None if I were to print(df)

Comment: Are you sure you defined dfSynsets and contents ?

Comment: why it show 1 problem, can you go in this section ?

Comment: What do you mean by going into this section? The for loop in the question was able to print the word matching. Maybe I can work around your code blocks for a bit if you're confident they do what the question intends

Comment: I think you want to find matching words and if there is a matching words you add json to a json column. If this is what you want to do this is a way to do it. I did not check the script because python is not installed on this computer ^^. If you find what is wrong tell me like that i correct my answer

Comment: I changed the conditional to be strictly equivalent words rather than an instance of it. And your help got me my desired output! I'll try to build more reputation in order to upvote your answer. Thank you!

Comment: Your welcome ! You can also clarify your questions so that people with similar problems find the answer more easily

Answer (score 0):

As per your questions, I ascertain that you want to traverse the JSON file and retrieve the value of the 'word' key, and compare the value with the last column of the CSV file. If the both the words are the same, print  **equal**, otherwise **'not equal'**.

If this is correct, then find the below approach:-

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(CSV FILE NAME)
row,col = df.shape
for value in contents['words']:
    current_word = value['word']
    for csv_row in range(row):
        curr_csv_word = df.loc[csv_row][-1]
        if curr_csv_word == current_word:
            print("EQUAL")
        else:
            print("NOT EQUAL")
```

I hope you find your answer.

Comment: I changed the logic a bit around for this one and got a promising result to build off of. Thank you!